# Making graphs of hadoop runs

Tags: hadoop, data-visualization

On some websites (like in this PDF : http://sortbenchmark.org/Yahoo2009.pdf) I see very nice graphs that visualize what an Hadoop cluster is doing at what moment.

Were these made "manually" (i.e. with some homemade tool) or is there a "ready to run" script/tool that produces something like this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owen made the graph manually in Excel by gathering data from the logs, though I've heard Karamsphere's tools will generate a similar graph.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for an "out of the box" hadoop tool that does this for me.